# converting a large integer representation into a specified base

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a class that represents very very large integers(ignore floats) as an array of numbers. For example, the first n bits are stored in index 0, the next n bits in index 1, and so on. This allows for representation of numbers beyond the limit of the primitive type.

My problem is converting the represented number into another base. How do I do conversion to binary, octal, or even base-3?